# Lapack routines for solving A x = 0

Tags: c++, c, fortran, numerical-methods, lapack

I am looking for a LAPACK routine that allows to find a non-trivial solution to the following equation:

***A x*** = **0**

provided that ***A*** is a *n*×*n* square singular non-symmetric band matrix.

In reality ***A*** matrix may not be exactly singular as it is based on some parameter and I use a root finding algorithm to find this parameter (requiring det(***A***) = 0, where the determinant is found with DGBTRF and multiplication of the diagonal elements).

The only solution I have came up so far is to consider ***A*** a dense matrix matrix, use DGEEV to find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors and take the eigenvector for the eigenvalue closest to zero. However, I believe this is strongly sub-optimal approach. Can anyone suggest a better one?

Comment: If there is a non-trivial solution to this, then there are infinitely many solutions. Do you just want any solution?

Comment: Yes, any would be fine. In most cases what I am looking for is a situation when the rank of A is smaller by one than its dimension, so I will have just one linearly independent solution.

In the ideal case, though, I would be even more happy to have all the linearly independent solutions if the rank of A is smaller than n–1.

In any case I don't mind the scaling.

Comment: Probably better suited for http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Indeed - I strongly suspect this is really a duplicate of http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10185/solving-for-null-space-of-a-matrix-with-mkl-lapack

Comment: Looks like it is... Closing the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I found out that this is a copy of http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10185/solving-for-null-space-of-a-matrix-with-mkl-lapack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably [Inverse Iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration).

Lapack does implement this for upper Hessenberg Matrices ([DHSEIN](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dhsein.f)) and also has routines to compute the upper Hessenber Form of a general Matrix (PxGEHRD).

Since you only need a single Eigenvector, it might be faster to just use an Inverse Iteration on the original matrix, especially if you can give a good initial guess for the solution. As that is easy to implement, you can just try both and see what is faster.

(This is assuming that there still is some Eigenvalue close to 0, if that error is too big, you need to recalculate the eigenvalues.)